# Python profiling using line_profiler - clever way to remove @profile statements on-the-fly?

Tags: python, profiling, decorator, python-decorators

I want to use the excellent [line_profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler), but only some of the time. To make it work I add

```
@profile
```

before every function call, e.g.

```
@profile
def myFunc(args):
    blah
    return
```

and execute

```
kernprof.py -l -v mycode.py args
```

But I don't want to have to put the `@profile` decorators in by hand each time, because most of the time I want to execute the code without them, and I get an exception if I try to include them, e.g.

```
mycode.py args
```

Is there a happy medium where I can dynamically have the decorators removed based on some condition switch/argument, without having to do things manually and/or modify each function too much?

Comment: I'd ask myself if I really need to profile so frequently that it needs such support. I'm not saying you do or don't, so you needn't answer. I just found the use case a little surprising.

Comment: The code takes a long time (hours at the moment...) to execute, so for now I want to kill two birds with one stone in getting results and profiling simultaneously. I suppose I see profiling as an ongoing process (since I'm new to/excited about it), so I wouldn't just use it in the (many) functions, declare it done and remove all the decorators.

Comment: I wouldn't let something take hours without [*trying this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771). It costs nothing and tells you exactly what's going on.

Comment: @jtlz2 You can also wrap functions and class methods to profile (possibly in a separate profiling script) and avoid adding `@profile` decorators entirely as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376466/5874320).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of *removing* the `@profile` decorator lines, provide your own pass-through no-op version.

You can add the following code to your project somewhere:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    import __builtin__ as builtins
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    import builtins

try:
    builtins.profile
except AttributeError:
    # No line profiler, provide a pass-through version
    def profile(func): return func
    builtins.profile = profile
```

Import this before any code using the `@profile` decorator and you can use the code with or without the line profiler being active.

Because the dummy decorator is a pass-through function, execution performance is not impacted (only import performance is *every so lightly* affected).

If you don't like messing with built-ins, you can make this a separate module; say `profile_support.py`:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    import __builtin__ as builtins
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    import builtins

try:
    profile = builtins.profile
except AttributeError:
    # No line profiler, provide a pass-through version
    def profile(func): return func
```

(no *assignment* to `builtins.profile`) and use `from profile_support import profile` in any module that uses the `@profile` decorator.

Comment: The issue with this is that if you want to "prime" your run with something like `kernprof -l --setup script.py script.py`, It will overwrite the @profile decorator with noop for both runs.

Comment: @JonnyRobbie: then use another decorator that determines if `builtins.profile` exists when the script is run, not when it is imported. What happens with `--setup` is that the code is imported with `builtins.profile` not set, all your code is decorated with the no-op decorator, and so nothing is being profiled on the actual profiling run.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to import `__builtins__`/`builtins` or `LineProfiler` at all, you can simply rely on a `NameError` when trying to lookup `profile`:

```
try:
    profile
except NameError:
    profile = lambda x: x
```

However this needs to be included in every file that uses `profile`, but it doesn't (permanently) alter the global state (builtins) of Python.

Answer (score 6):

A comment that grew to become a variant of @Martijin Pieters answer.

I prefer not to involve `__builtin__` at all. W/o a comment, it would be practically impossible for someone else to guess that `line_profiler` is involved, w/o a priori knowing this.

Looking at `kernprof` [line 199](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/a2f484a3ba099406d83cb22ff834b008d7c6465f/kernprof.py#L199), it suffices to instantiate `LineProfiler`.

```
try:
    from line_profiler import LineProfiler
    profile = LineProfiler()
except ImportError:
    def profile(func):
        return func
```

Importing (explicit) [is better](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) than globally modifying `builtins` (implicit). If the profiling decorators are permanent, then their origin should be clear in the code itself.

In presence of `line_profiler`, the above approach will wrap the decorated functions with profilers on every run, irrespective of whether run by `kernprof`. This side-effect may be undesired.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following modified version with Python 3.4

```
try:
    import builtins
    profile = builtins.__dict__['profile']
except KeyError:
    # No line profiler, provide a pass-through version
    def profile(func): return func
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but those may pose an issue when trying to "prime" the script with something like `kernprof -l --setup script.py script.py`. Priming your script like this may be useful for example when you try to optimize your functions with `numba` and you don't want to bias your line timings with compiling (or loading from filesystem cache, which still has a significant overhead even with numbas cache=True param).

The issue is that the setup run noops all your `@profile` decorators and renders them moot for the profiling run.

I solved that by moving the try except to the actual decorator run like this:

```
def profile2(f):
    def s(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return profile(f)(*args, **kwargs)
        except NameError:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return s
```

and decorating all my profiled function with `@profile2`.