# Python line_profiler code example

Tags: python, profiling, line-profiler

I am trying to figure out how I can run Python's [line_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler) to get the line by line execution times in the format given in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927628/how-can-i-profile-python-code-line-by-line/3927671#3927671).

I installed the module and am calling its `LineProfiler` object as below but the output I get is just a single time and not a line by line summary.

Any ideas? Furthermore, how can I get the time for the `numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]` line that is outside any function?

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_stuff(numbers):

    s = sum(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
profile = LineProfiler(do_stuff(numbers))
profile.print_stats()
[] Timer unit: 3.20721e-07 s
```

Answer (score 51):

The `line_profiler` test cases (found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/master/tests/test_line_profiler.py#L63)) have an example of how to generate profile data from within a Python script. You have to wrap the function that you want to profile and then call the wrapper passing any desired function arguments.

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_stuff(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
lp = LineProfiler()
lp_wrapper = lp(do_stuff)
lp_wrapper(numbers)
lp.print_stats()
```

Output:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.000649 s
File: <ipython-input-2-2e060b054fea>
Function: do_stuff at line 4

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           def do_stuff(numbers):
     5         1           10     10.0      1.5      s = sum(numbers)
     6         1          186    186.0     28.7      l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
     7         1          453    453.0     69.8      m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]
```

**Adding Additional Functions to Profile**

Also, you can add additional functions to be profiled as well. For example, if you had a second *called* function and you only wrap the *calling* function, you'll only see the profile results from the *calling* function.

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_other_stuff(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)

def do_stuff(numbers):
    do_other_stuff(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
lp = LineProfiler()
lp_wrapper = lp(do_stuff)
lp_wrapper(numbers)
lp.print_stats()
```

The above would only produce the following profile output for the *calling* function:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.000773 s
File: <ipython-input-3-ec0394d0a501>
Function: do_stuff at line 7

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           def do_stuff(numbers):
     8         1           11     11.0      1.4      do_other_stuff(numbers)
     9         1          236    236.0     30.5      l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    10         1          526    526.0     68.0      m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]
```

In this case, you can add the additional *called* function to profile like this:

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_other_stuff(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)

def do_stuff(numbers):
    do_other_stuff(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
lp = LineProfiler()
lp.add_function(do_other_stuff)   # add additional function to profile
lp_wrapper = lp(do_stuff)
lp_wrapper(numbers)
lp.print_stats()
```

Output:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 9e-06 s
File: <ipython-input-4-dae73707787c>
Function: do_other_stuff at line 4

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           def do_other_stuff(numbers):
     5         1            9      9.0    100.0      s = sum(numbers)

Total time: 0.000694 s
File: <ipython-input-4-dae73707787c>
Function: do_stuff at line 7

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           def do_stuff(numbers):
     8         1           12     12.0      1.7      do_other_stuff(numbers)
     9         1          208    208.0     30.0      l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    10         1          474    474.0     68.3      m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]
```

NOTE: Adding functions to profile in this way does not require changes to the profiled code (i.e., no need to add `@profile` decorators).

Answer (score 8):

As described in the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/#line-profiler):

> in your script, you can decorate any function you want to profile with @profile

You want to decorate your `do_stuff` function with `@profile` and then run

```
kernprof -v -l script_to_profile.py
```

to get the annotated output printed to your terminal. The profile will also be written to `script_to_profile.py.lprof` and you can re-create the output later with

```
python -m line_profiler script_to_profile.py.lprof
```

Comment: I think now kernprof -v -l script_to_profile.py not kernprof.py -v -l script_to_profile.py

Comment: Thanks, updated. Seems there is now `kernprof` as console script.