# How do I use line_profiler (from Robert Kern)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, profiling, line-profiler

I have tried using the line_profiler module for getting a line-by-line profile over a Python file. This is what I've done so far:

1) Installed line_profiler from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler) by using the .exe file (I am on WinXP and Win7). Just clicked through the installation wizard.

2) Written a small piece of code (similar to what has been asked in another answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328183/python-line-profiler-code-example)).

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
def do_stuff(numbers):
    print numbers

numbers = 2
profile = LineProfiler(do_stuff(numbers))
profile.print_stats()
```

3) Run the code from IDLE/PyScripter. I got only the time.

```
Timer unit: 4.17188e-10 s
```

How do I get full line-by-line profile over the code I execute? I have never used any advanced Python features like decorators, so it is hard for me to understand how shall I use the guidelines provided by several posts like [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140513005858im_/http://www.appneta.com/blog/line-profiler-python/) and [here](http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just follow Dan Riti's example from the first [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140513005858im_/http://www.appneta.com/blog/line-profiler-python/), but use your code. All you have to do after installing the `line_profiler` module is add a `@profile` decorator right before each function you wish to profile line-by-line and make sure each one is called at least once somewhere else in the code—so for your trivial example code that would be something like this:

`example.py` file:

```
@profile
def do_stuff(numbers):
    print numbers

numbers = 2
do_stuff(numbers)
```

Having done that, run your script via the `kernprof.py`<sup>**✶**</sup> that was installed in your `C:\Python27\Scripts` directory. Here's the (not very interesting) actual output from doing this in a Windows 7 command-line session:

```
> python "C:\Python27\Scripts\kernprof.py" -l -v example.py
2
Wrote profile results to example.py.lprof
Timer unit: 3.2079e-07 s

File: example.py
Function: do_stuff at line 2
Total time: 0.00185256 s

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           @profile
     2                                           def do_stuff(numbers):
     3         1         5775   5775.0    100.0      print numbers
```

You likely need to adapt this last step—the running of your test script with `kernprof.py` instead of directly by the Python interpreter—in order to do the equivalent from within IDLE or PyScripter.

**<sup>✶</sup>Update**

It appears that in `line_profiler` v1.0, the `kernprof` utility is  distributed as an executable, not a `.py` script file as it was when I wrote the above. This means the following now needs to used to invoke it from the command-line:

```
> "C:\Python27\Scripts\kernprof.exe" -l -v example.py
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, if you want to run the script normally (without `kernprof.py`) you'll need to remove the `@profile` decorator call(s) or define your own dummy one: e.g. `profile = lambda f: f` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: This isn't working for me because I don't seem to be able to call kernprof.py. I used pip install to get line_profiler and a file called kernprof is there but it doesn't have the .py extension, do you know why this would be? Thank you.

Comment: @Alex: No idea...could be a bad install. Try it again and it that doesn't work do it manually without `pip` by downloading the module's source from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/1.0).

Comment: @Alex `kernprof` doesn't have to have `.py` extension to be executable. Mine installs inside a venv and runs fine as simply `kernprof`.

Comment: @martineau Do you know why the original code didn't gather statistics? It is a minimal example and the invocation "looks ok" to me. Seems to run fine when one replaces `LineProfiler(..)` with `cProfile.Profile(...)`.

Comment: @szalski: I assume it's because the `@profile` decorator wasn't applied to any functions, so no statistics were gathered to print. You might be able to figure it out by looking at the source code.

Comment: @everyone: There's a newer version of Kern's `line_profiler` utility available (currently 2.1.2). You can get it from [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=line_profiler) or from the project's [homepage](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler). From what's shown in the change-log there, it looks like it's supported Python 3 since the first non-beta release of version 1.0.

Comment: For Python 3.10, use this command: `python -m kernprof -l -v "script with things added for profiler.py"`and it prints the result to the command line as expected. (I installed kernprof today using `pip install line_profiler`)

Answer (score 88):

This answer is a copy of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43376466/5874320) for how to get `line_profiler` statistics from within a Python script (without using `kernprof` from the command line or having to add `@profile` decorators to functions and class methods). All answers (that I've seen) to similar `line_profiler` questions only describe using `kernprof`.

---

The `line_profiler` test cases (found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/master/tests/test_line_profiler.py#L63)) have an example of how to generate profile data from within a Python script. You have to wrap the function that you want to profile and then call the wrapper passing any desired function arguments.

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_stuff(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
lp = LineProfiler()
lp_wrapper = lp(do_stuff)
lp_wrapper(numbers)
lp.print_stats()
```

Output:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.000649 s
File: <ipython-input-2-2e060b054fea>
Function: do_stuff at line 4

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           def do_stuff(numbers):
     5         1           10     10.0      1.5      s = sum(numbers)
     6         1          186    186.0     28.7      l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
     7         1          453    453.0     69.8      m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]
```

**Adding Additional Functions to Profile**

Also, you can add additional functions to be profiled as well. For example, if you had a second *called* function and you only wrap the *calling* function, you'll only see the profile results from the *calling* function.

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_other_stuff(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)

def do_stuff(numbers):
    do_other_stuff(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
lp = LineProfiler()
lp_wrapper = lp(do_stuff)
lp_wrapper(numbers)
lp.print_stats()
```

The above would only produce the following profile output for the *calling* function:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 0.000773 s
File: <ipython-input-3-ec0394d0a501>
Function: do_stuff at line 7

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           def do_stuff(numbers):
     8         1           11     11.0      1.4      do_other_stuff(numbers)
     9         1          236    236.0     30.5      l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    10         1          526    526.0     68.0      m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]
```

In this case, you can add the additional *called* function to profile like this:

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_other_stuff(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)

def do_stuff(numbers):
    do_other_stuff(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
lp = LineProfiler()
lp.add_function(do_other_stuff)   # add additional function to profile
lp_wrapper = lp(do_stuff)
lp_wrapper(numbers)
lp.print_stats()
```

Output:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 9e-06 s
File: <ipython-input-4-dae73707787c>
Function: do_other_stuff at line 4

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           def do_other_stuff(numbers):
     5         1            9      9.0    100.0      s = sum(numbers)

Total time: 0.000694 s
File: <ipython-input-4-dae73707787c>
Function: do_stuff at line 7

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     7                                           def do_stuff(numbers):
     8         1           12     12.0      1.7      do_other_stuff(numbers)
     9         1          208    208.0     30.0      l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    10         1          474    474.0     68.3      m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]
```

NOTE: Adding functions to profile in this way does not require changes to the profiled code (i.e., no need to add `@profile` decorators).

Comment: Good answer! But I actually find the decorators a good way to control profiling. Is there a way to use line_prof with decorators within-script (without kernprof)?

Comment: I'm not 100% this works. I haven't tested it yet. 

Thanks to tdube for the line_profiler code. All I did was convert an existing decorator I had to hopefully work with LineProfiler.

EDIT: formatting was messed up because I can't figure out how to format code in comments. [Here's a Pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/vgFhxjxF)

Comment: That's what I'm using currently in my Django code (where I can't use command line `kernprof`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/68163807/1937033

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the entire script? I mean I could technically make it one big function but that seems pretty overkill

Answer (score 8):

Found a good use to `line_profiler` using decorator i.e. `@profile` that worked for me:

```
def profile(func):
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        from line_profiler import LineProfiler
        prof = LineProfiler()
        try:
            return prof(func)(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            prof.print_stats()

    return wrapper
```

Credits to: [pavelpatrin](https://gist.github.com/pavelpatrin/5a28311061bf7ac55cdd)

Answer (score 6):

#### load the line_profiler and numpy

```
%load_ext line_profiler
import numpy as np
```

#### define a function for example:

```
def take_sqr(array):
    sqr_ar = [np.sqrt(x) for x in array]
    return sqr_ar
```

#### use line_profiler to count the time as follows:

```
%lprun -f take_sqr take_sqr([1,2,3])
```

#### the output looks like this:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s
 
Total time: 6e-05 s File: <ipython-input-5-e50c1b05a473> Function:
take_sqr at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def take_sqr(array):
     2         4         59.0     14.8     98.3      sqr_ar = [np.sqrt(x) for x in array]
     3         1          1.0      1.0      1.7      return sqr_ar
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please include a brief description of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I just edited the response. I hope you find it clearer now.

Comment: I used just this way but I would like to suppress that output because I don't need that by now (only need output during debug)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using PyCharm, you can also take a look at
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16536-line-profiler

It's a plugin I created that allows you to load and visualize line profiler results into the PyCharm editor.

Comment: Do you have any manual on how to remove the values once you want to retake coding?, congrats by the way, this is pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to @Lhenkel [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69792177/2248627).
This is a decorator for async functions

```py
def async_profile(func):
    """line profiler for an async funciton"""
    from functools import wraps

    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        from line_profiler import LineProfiler
        prof = LineProfiler()
        try:
            return await prof(func)(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            prof.print_stats()

    return wrapper
```

To use these decorators with methods read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944992/2248627)