# Kernprof (line_profiler): how to output result as text instead of a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, line-profiler

When running kernprof:

```
kernprof -l script_to_profile.py
```

The output is stored in a binary file, which can be read in the terminal/command line.

Is there a way to output the results to a text file?

This seems like useful functionality to have, but can't find it in the documentation or in other posts.

Comment: See [How do I use line_profiler (from Robert Kern)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885147/how-do-i-use-line-profiler-from-robert-kern).

Comment: Read the page you mentioned (before posting this question) -> but I don't think it has any mention of outputting to a text file.

Comment: The `kernprof` outputs to stdout, so redirect that to a file.

Comment: By default that output is a binary file (at least on my system) -> i.e. it needs to be read by issuing the command: "python -m line_profiler script_to_profile.py.lprof", which will print the contents to the command line. I am looking to output to a text file directly. What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like they must have changed it. Unfortunately `pip install line_profiler` is [broken](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler#id5) in the current release, so I can't install the latest version. Regardless, can't you do something like `python -m line_profiler script_to_profile.py.lprof > profile_output.txt`?

Comment: Amazing, that works. Thanks!

Comment: have posted your solution, if you post I'll mark yours as accepted

Comment: PvK: That's not necessary, but thanks for offering. Glad to hear you've found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
python -m line_profiler script_to_profile.py.lprof > profile_output.txt
```

Will convert the binary output to a text file (thanks @martineau)