# how to make a python project less laggy and slow?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle
from math import fabs

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("Ray Caster")
window.bgcolor("#000000")
window.setup(1000, 500)
window.tracer(0, 0)
window.delay(0)

char = turtle.Turtle()
char.color("#ffff00")
char.penup()
char.shape("triangle")
char.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.4, stretch_len=0.8)

ray = char.clone()
ray.shape("square")
ray.shapesize(stretch_len=0.2, stretch_wid=0.2)
ray.pencolor("#0000ff")
ray.pensize(1)

fov = 60

def single_ray():
    ray.goto(char.position())
    ray.pendown()
    for i in range(1000):
        ray.forward(4)
        if collision(ray, rigwall, 8, 20, 16, 500) or collision(ray, lefwall, 8, 20, 16, 500) or collision(ray, topwall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(ray, botwall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(ray, midwall, 8, 500, 16, 20):
        ray.backward(4)
    ray.penup()

def raycast():
    ray.right(fov / 2)
    for i in range(fov):
        single_ray()
        ray.left(1)

def ray_cast():
    ray.clear()
    ray.setheading(char.heading())
    raycast()

def collision(a, b, a_width, b_width, a_height, b_height):
    xcoll = (fabs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) * 2) < (a_width + b_width)
    ycoll = (fabs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) * 2) < (a_height + b_height)
    return (xcoll and ycoll)

rigwall = turtle.Turtle()
rigwall.color("#444444")
rigwall.shape("square")
rigwall.shapesize(stretch_wid=25, stretch_len=1)
rigwall.penup()
rigwall.goto(480, 0)

lefwall = rigwall.clone()
lefwall.goto(-490, 0)

topwall = rigwall.clone()
topwall.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=50)
topwall.goto(0, 240)

botwall = topwall.clone()
botwall.goto(0, -230)

midwall = topwall.clone()
midwall.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=25)
midwall.goto(0, 100)

def char_for():
    char.forward(5)
def char_bac():
    char.backward(5)
def char_lef():
    char.left(4.5)
def char_rig():
    char.right(4.5)

window.listen()
window.onkeypress(char_for, "w")
window.onkeypress(char_bac, "s")
window.onkeypress(char_lef, "a")
window.onkeypress(char_rig, "d")

while 1:

    if collision(char, rigwall, 8, 20, 16, 500) or collision(char, lefwall, 8, 20, 16, 500) or collision(char, topwall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(char, botwall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(char, midwall, 8, 500, 16, 20):
        char.backward(5)

    ray_cast()

    window.update()
```

I'm trying to create a ray tracer to make a 3d game using turtle python but using anymore lines(fov) than 10 makes the program become laggy. I was wondering if anyone could help?
I used things like tracer, update and speed but nothing is working well. please may anyone help because I'm kind of new to coding and am stuck.

Comment: Have you tried to using Python 3.11? Is 10% to 60% faster than python3.10

Comment: A profiler can identify where you're spending most of your runtime. That does sound a bit like a big-O issue, so get a code review of any algorithm that loops over the lines. This isn't really a specific issue with anything we can look at, so not much more I can say.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: On first glance, single_ray might be doing a lot of work each cycle. It seems to work, just poorly, but you don't have any specific question. This might be better on stackreview. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ray tracing is very computationally heavy. You will have to used some advanced techniques to improve performance, such as figuring out a way to do the calculations on the GPU instead of the CPU.

Comment: In single_ray, shortening the for loop to a max length of 10 makes it much more responsive. Good luck.

Comment: `while 1: update()` is not a good pattern. This just slams the CPU as hard as possible and isn't consistent from one frame to the next or one computer to another. You might try `ontimer`.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a ray tracer in Python? As great as Python is, it's not suitable for *some* applications. Outside of small cases it's too slow for an app that by its nature requires so much CPU time.

Nevertheless:

1. Use `kernprof` to find time that functions spend executing, the output is highly readable: [How do I use line_profiler (from Robert Kern)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885147/how-do-i-use-line-profiler-from-robert-kern)
2. Refactor this a bit for PyPy, it's substantially faster in many cases than CPython.
3. Desperate times call for desperate measures: Cython. After profiling CPython code, rewrite CPU hogging parts in Cython. Profile the code again in Cython, it has a nice built-in profiler.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem I see here is:

```
for i in range(1000):
    ray.forward(4)
    if collision(...) or ...:
        ray.backward(4)
```

It seems to me we need a `break` after `ray.backward(4)` otherwise we're going to continue (re)testing (roughly 500 times) something we know will fail.  A lesser optimization would be here:

```
def collision(a, b, a_width, b_width, a_height, b_height):
    xcoll = (fabs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) * 2) < (a_width + b_width)
    ycoll = (fabs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) * 2) < (a_height + b_height)
    return (xcoll and ycoll)
```

If `xcoll` is `False`, there's no point to computing `ycoll`:

```
def collision(a, b, a_width, b_width, a_height, b_height):
    if (fabs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) * 2) < (a_width + b_width):
        return (fabs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) * 2) < (a_height + b_height)

    return False
```

My rework of your code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import fabs

FOV = 60

def single_ray():
    ray.goto(char.position())
    ray.pendown()

    for _ in range(1000):
        ray.forward(4)

        if collision(ray, middle_wall, 8, 500, 16, 20) or collision(ray, top_wall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(ray, bottom_wall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(ray, right_wall, 8, 20, 16, 500) or collision(ray, left_wall, 8, 20, 16, 500):
            ray.undo()
            break

    ray.penup()

def ray_cast():
    ray.clear()
    ray.setheading(char.heading())
    ray.right(FOV / 2)

    for _ in range(FOV):
        single_ray()
        ray.left(1)

def collision(a, b, a_width, b_width, a_height, b_height):
    if (fabs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) * 2) < (a_width + b_width):
        return (fabs(a.ycor() - b.ycor()) * 2) < (a_height + b_height)

    return False

def char_forward():
    char.forward(5)

def char_backward():
    char.backward(5)

def char_left():
    char.left(4.5)

def char_right():
    char.right(4.5)

def run():
    if collision(char, middle_wall, 8, 500, 16, 20) or collision(char, top_wall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(char, bottom_wall, 8, 1000, 16, 20) or collision(char, right_wall, 8, 20, 16, 500) or collision(char, left_wall, 8, 20, 16, 500):
        char.backward(5)

    ray_cast()

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(run)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Ray Caster")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(1000, 500)
screen.tracer(False)

char = Turtle()
char.shape('triangle')
char.color('yellow')
char.shapesize(stretch_wid=0.4, stretch_len=0.8)
char.penup()

ray = char.clone()
ray.shape('square')
ray.pencolor('blue')
ray.shapesize(stretch_len=0.2, stretch_wid=0.2)
ray.pensize(1)

right_wall = Turtle()
right_wall.color('gray')
right_wall.shape('square')
right_wall.shapesize(stretch_wid=25, stretch_len=1)
right_wall.penup()
right_wall.setx(480)

left_wall = right_wall.clone()
left_wall.setx(-490)

top_wall = right_wall.clone()
top_wall.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=50)
top_wall.setposition(0, 240)

bottom_wall = top_wall.clone()
bottom_wall.sety(-230)

middle_wall = top_wall.clone()
middle_wall.shapesize(stretch_len=25)
middle_wall.sety(100)

screen.onkeypress(char_forward, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(char_backward, 's')
screen.onkeypress(char_left, 'a')
screen.onkeypress(char_right, 'd')
screen.listen()
screen.update()

run()

screen.exitonclick()
```