# Python inefficient loop despite its simplicity

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops

I've tried to run this little code, it just takes random points (here 50k, near of what I have in reality) and returns the 10th nearest points for each point randomly selected.

But unfortunately this is (really !) long because of the loop for sure.

As I'm pretty new in 'code optimization', is there a trick to make this mush faster ? (Faster at Python scale I know I'm not coding in C++).

Here is a reproducible example with data size close to what I have:

```py
import time

import numpy as np
from numpy import random
from scipy.spatial import distance

# USEFUL FUNCTION

start_time = time.time()


def closest_node(node, nodes):
    nodes = np.asarray(nodes)
    deltas = nodes - node
    dist_2 = np.einsum("ij,ij->i", deltas, deltas)
    ndx = dist_2.argsort()
    return data[ndx[:10]]


# REPRODUCIBLE DATA

mean = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
cov = np.array([[1.0, -0.5, 0.8], [-0.5, 1.1, 0.0], [0.8, 0.0, 1.0]])
data = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 500000)

# START RUNNING

points = data[np.random.choice(data.shape[0], int(np.round(0.1 * len(data), 0)))]
print(len(points))

for w in points:
    closest_node(w, data)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Nice first question. It is well contained and you have a working example. However, it is not clear to me exactly what you are asking. Is is _why_ the code is slow?

Comment: Your code combines two algorithmic complexities: the first one is the loop `w in points`, obviously linear in len(points). But the second one is `dist_2.argsort`, which is typically O(N log(N)) ... but with N=len(data)=500000 in your case; this is the expensive part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time it takes to run `argsort` every loop on your 500000 element array is huge. The only improvement I can think of is to use something that can return the smallest 10 elements without fully sorting the whole array.

[A fast way to find the largest N elements in an numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337533/a-fast-way-to-find-the-largest-n-elements-in-an-numpy-array)

So instead of

```
ndx = dist_2.argsort() 
return data[ndx[:10]]
```

It would be

```
ndx = np.argpartition(dist_2, 10)[:10]
return data[ndx[:10]]
```

I only benchmarked on 500 points because it already took quite some time to run on my PC.

```
N=500
Using argsort: 25.625439167022705 seconds
Using argpartition: 6.637120485305786 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be probably best off analyzing the slowest points via profiler: [How do I find out what parts of my code are inefficient in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893768/how-do-i-find-out-what-parts-of-my-code-are-inefficient-in-python)

One thing that might be possible at first glance, is that you should probably move as much as possible outside loop. If you are going to convert points via np.asarray(), it possibly might be better to do it once for all points before the loop, and use the result in function, rather than doing np.asarray() in each loop run.

Comment: `np.asarray` should be a no-op if it's argument is already a `numpy.ndarray`, which seems to be the case here